# How can I read an ini file in to have the different methods of fittings of gsl?

Tags: c, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization, gsl, model-fitting

I am currently working on a code with c and have different gsl fitting methods ( dogleg, double dogleg , Levenberg Marquardt and Levenberg Marquardt with geodesic acceleration) i would like to have an ini file where i say which fit method i am using and have the program read it and pick that method . I've never done this before though, so any hints on where to start would be very appreciated.

I'm using nonlinear, least squares fitting. Some example are shown in the official gsl website

[Gsl different fitting methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/nls.html)

The method selection is through the interface :

gsl_multifit_nlinear_trs_lm; (for Levenberg Marquardt)

gsl_multifit_nlinear_trs_dogleg; (for dogleg)

Instead of changing which method i want everytime in my code , i would like to select it using an ini file . I hope this makes sense.

Comment: For me it is unclear what your actual problem is. Is it reading the file, calling the correct function, providing correct data to the different functions, ...? You might provide some sample code to illustrate what needs to be changed for different variants.

Comment: Which OS are you on?  You can use libconfig on Linux or GetPrivateProfileString in Windows.  If you wish to go OTT, look up TOML, where you can go absolutely crazy.  Then if you just want to get the job done without being overly clever about it, it is just a bunch of strcmps to pick out the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a mapping structure containing the string name of the functions and a function pointer.

I'll give an example using two functions that have the same signature. If you have functions that takes different sets of arguments, you should also have a void pointer to an argument structure that you will then pass to a wrapper function. But that's a whole different thing.

```
/* load.c
 *
 *  2023-03-30
 */
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> /* strcmp */

struct map_t {
    /* MAGIC 64: use a macro... */
    char name[64];
    void (*func)(void);
};

void foo_a(void) {
    printf("foo_a\n");
}

void foo_b(void) {
    printf("foo_b\n");
}

#define MAP(a)      {# a, a}
/* MAGIC 2: use another macro for the mapping size */
struct map_t map[2] = {
    MAP(foo_a),
    MAP(foo_b)
    //{"foo_a", foo_a},
    //{"foo_b", foo_b}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* lazy file ops, should do error checking */
    FILE *fp;
    char line[100];
    fp = fopen("load.ini", "r");
    fgets(line, 100, fp);
    /* remove newline, if there is one */
    char *s = strchr(line, '\n');
    if(s) *s = 0;
    fclose(fp);

    /* MAGIC 2 here. You should keep track of the map structure
     * size in some variable or MACRO and use it here instead
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(map[i].name, line)) {
            map[i].func();
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

`struct map_t` is what will hold our mappings.
`map[2]` is the map itself, and I use a macro to show you that you can use the preprocessor to make things easier on yourself on more complex mappings (bellow are the commented generated code).
`foo_a` and `foo_b` are the functions. Not that both of them have the same signature, and that I use this signature in the mapping structure `void (*func)(void)`.

If they had another signature, say, `float *crazy_function(int a, double b)`, then the pointer would be `float (*func)(int, double)`. If all the functions share the same signature, you can use it like this. Otherwise, you should have another structure that will have all the possible arguments, and wrapper functions that will call the ones you need.

There's a file called "load.ini" in the directory, and the file is just one line, just one string.

Testing:

```
$ make load
$ echo "foo_a" > load.ini
$ ./load
foo_a
$ echo "foo_b" > load.ini
$ ./load
foo_b
$
```

You could also use `argv` instead of a file, then just call the program based on that:

```
$ ./load foo_a
$ ./load foo_b
```

Comment: This answer is not suitable for the level on which the question is asked. The question displays no comprehension of the numerous issues involved in supporting an initialization file and explicitly asks where to start. This answer focuses on a specific aspect of a specific solution, omitting any orientation or discussion of preparatory issues. Its solution, mapping strings to function pointers, is likely overkill. This answer presents code that opens a file in the “current directory” without any discussion of appropriate locations for initialization files…

Comment: … Often initialization files are stored in a home directory or in a system-designated preferences folder. Or they may be read from the current directory, if suitable for the application. Initialization files often use a name that makes them “hidden”, such as beginning with a “.”. The code in this answer attempts to open a file and immediately attempts to read from it without checking whether the open succeeded, but a program should gracefully handle absent initialization files, and that is an important part of an answer to a question asking where to start…

Comment: … Then there are issues of parsing the initialization file, handling errors in the expected format, and so on. While it may seem fine to read one line and match it to a keyword, that is a thoughtless plan that does not consider adding options in the future. The answer presents a solution of mapping strings to function pointers without saying why or discussing alternatives, such as simple using the flag to set variable (possible an enumeration variable) to a value indicating what method to use…

Comment: … The macro stringification operator is used without explaining it, but we can expect a person asking on this question might not be familiar with it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil there are several different solutions, this is one of them. Another one could be enums, or environment variables, or flag files, or even symbolic links and checking `argv[0]`. "Why" use this? Well, it solves the problem, that's a reason. Reading files, where to store them and nomenclature are out of scope on a question that asks: "how to read from a file and use a function" - direct interpretation of that, as humans, is "i'll give you a name, you give me a function", that's a string comparison problem....

Comment: @EricPostpischil Macro stringification is explained by example: right bellow it are commented-out lines of the "to be generated" code. Further, I always had the idea that SO answers to specific questions should provide working code that gives you a conceptual framework to solve your specific problem. I don't see the point of handing out 150 lines of code that does error checking on everything, meaning that the essence of the solution gets convoluted in boilerplate code.

Comment: Re “Reading files, where to store them and nomenclature are out of scope on a question that asks…”: No, they are not out of scope; they are fundamental to supporting initialization files.

Comment: Re “there are several different solutions, this is one of them”: Stack Overflow is not intended as a site to provide code. It is a site intended to provide answers to questions. Answers should primarily explain concepts, not provide code.

Comment: Re “Macro stringification is explained by example”: That is not an explanation.   It does not explain that it uses a (so-called) preprocessing feature to convert a token to a string nor that the `#` character triggers that.

Comment: Re “question that asks: "how to read from a file and use a function"”: The text you have in quotes does not appear in the question, and it does not represent what the question asks. Supporting an initialization file feature is not just reading from a file or using a function.